# what does this mean "couldn't read CGI input from STDIN after alloc read 0 "

Tags: java, network-programming, cgi

Iam trying to read a response from a CGI page from Java where I send a POST request with appropriate params using the apache commons HTTPClient library. 
I have framed the request with the request headers as like as browser, the java code responds with

**

> "couldn't read CGI input from STDIN
>   after alloc read 0"

**
When the same CGI when used in the browser works fine what could be the reason for this or Iam missing any params.

Here is the code

```
post.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3");
    post.addHeader("Host","www.XXX.yyy.in");
    post.addHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    post.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
    post.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
    post.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
    post.addHeader("Keep-Alive", "115");
    post.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    post.addHeader("Content-Header","10000");
    post.addHeader("Referer", "http://www.abc.info/");
            post.getParams().setParameter("buttonSubmit.x", "90");
    post.getParams().setParameter("buttonSubmit.y", "12");
    post.getParams().setParameter("lccp_1", "123");
    post.getParams().setParameter("lccp_2", "4567890");
    post.getParams().setParameter("texNumber", "1234567890");
    // code which submits to the CGI page
```

Comment: Care to share some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html

1.1.7.2. HTML forms

Do you need to use setEntity()? It would seem like the java code is detecting the presence of a request but is not receiving any actual data from it.